# Template metaprogramming rules of thumb

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, rules

What are the rules of thumb that should be considered whenever someone might use template metaprogramming to accomplish a goal? And what would be a **good** example where using template metaprogramming is much more efficient than plain old code other than libraries like **boost**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very helpful rule I can think of is to have the a compilation error be thrown as close to the "true" problem as possible.  That ways it's easier not only to deduce the issue but also easier for others who would use your library to deduce the issue.

Here's a contrived version of what I mean:

```
template<typename Type> struct convert{};
template<> struct convert<double>{ static const int value = D_COORD; };
template<> struct convert<Degree>{ static const int value = ANGLE_COORD; };
template<> struct convert<Radian>{ static const int value = RADIAN_COORD; };
```

for which you'll get a not as salient a description of the compiler error for attempting `convert<int>` when if you had simply made the first declaration a forward declaration then it would tell you immediately that there is no type defined for "convert."

As far as a good example, I'm afraid I'll have to defer to someone else.  However, you might want to take a look at [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/).  It's not Boost but it sure is awesome.